# 'create tablespace' from VARIABLE

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to

```
CREATE TABLESPACE l_tablespace ...
```

where l_tablespace defined as

```
VARIABLE l_tablespace VARCHAR2( 100 CHAR )
EXEC l_tablespace := 'my_tablespace';
```

Not `CREATE TABLESPACE l_tablespace ...` nor `CREATE TABLESPACE :l_tablespace ...` doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with [`execute immediate`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/executeimmediate_statement.htm)

```
execute immediate 'create tablespace '||l_tablespace||'  ...';
```

Comment: yeah, that's how I've dealt with it in my previous project. But it doesn't look like a good thing to me. Don't like it at all.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use bind variables in DDL, even in dynamic SQL, which is why your second attempt didn't work and why you have to use concatenation as @bunting showed. (It's generally helpful to show the error you got, rather than just 'doesn't work').

If you're running a script from SQL*Plus and want to be able to specify the tablespace at run-time, you can [define a substitution variable](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#sthref443) instead:

```
DEFINE l_tablespace=my_tablespace
CREATE TABLESPACE &l_tablespace ...
```

The same variable can then be reused in subsequant commands in the same file, e.g. creating tables in your new tablespace.

You can also get the value from the user running the script with [`ACCEPT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#sthref498). Or use a positional parameter passed from the command line (`&1` etc.), though I'd be less comfortable with that in here.

(Not sure if `ACCEPT` works in SQL Developer, but I think the rest does).